# Run jasper report (created with iReport) from within python without jasperserver?

Tags: python, jasper-reports

Is there a way to run a jasper report from within python without using jasper server. We have jasper server up and running but there is some additional overhead by using this method and an extra layer of complexity. If it can be eliminated then great if not then our current solution will have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try pyJasper: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyJasper/0.4
I have no experience with that module myself.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question as pyJasper requires the Jasper server: """A simple python module to run and get generated reports deployed on a JasperServer. Module works by consuming the SOAP web service provided by the JasperServer. """ https://github.com/agaoglu/pyjasperclient

Comment: @dirkjot pyjasperclient is not the library mentioned in the answer.