# Python app to run JasperReport libraries - i.e. no JasperServer

Tags: python, jasper-reports

I'm looking to try and run Jasper reports (that have been written in iReports and exported to xml) from within a python application, without having to communicate with a JasperServer instance.  Is this possible?

I've done some googling and only come across a 2 year old SO question (where the suggested answer actually requires JasperServer):
[Run jasper report (created with iReport) from within python without jasperserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903557/run-jasper-report-created-with-ireport-from-within-python-without-jasperserver)

And something that looks kind of promising, except for the "It is obsolete" in the title:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576969-python-jasperreport-integration-it-is-obsolete/

I'm hoping it's obsolete because this is now an officially supported thing (dream on, Dave), but I can't find anything about it, if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Jasper Reports are not implemented in Python, so the only way to have it serving to your Python code is to have Jasper Server running and awaiting Python requests over REST or other remote way of communication.

Simply - no way to have Jasper without Jasper (server) in Python

Comment: I realise that Jasper is a java library, but it would still be (theoretically) possible to use it in python if someone had made the bindings to do so.  I'm really looking to minimise the requirements of our system, and just need to occasionally run a few reports, without the overhead of a full blown JasperServer with all of it's 'benefits' (like scheduling) which we have no need at all for :(

Answer (score 0):

I used [py4j](https://www.py4j.org/index.html). I had to write a small program in java.
Using [this as an example](https://o7planning.org/en/10293/calling-jasper-report-from-java-application), it was simple.

It was more difficult to configure the build environment and put all the dependencies for printing qr-codes.

Python example:

```
    from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
    gateway = JavaGateway()
    gateway.entry_point.pdf_from_json('e:/test.jasper', 'e:/test.json', 'e:/test.pdf')
```

Java example:

```
package jasper4py;

import py4j.GatewayServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;

public class JasperEntryPoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GatewayServer gatewayServer = new GatewayServer(new JasperEntryPoint());
        gatewayServer.start();
        System.out.println("Gateway Server Started");
    }

    public void pdf_from_json(String report, String data, String result) throws JRException, IOException {
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        JsonDataSource dataSource = new JsonDataSource(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream(data));
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, dataSource);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, result);
    }
}
```